# php soap header setenv correct

Tags: php, soap

Ok my wsdl server is expecting this as a call :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:esc="http://escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net" xmlns:impl="http://impl.escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <esc:login>
          <esc:in0>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <impl:password>++</impl:password>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <impl:user>++</impl:user>
          </esc:in0>
       </esc:login>
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

but my php soap call is equal to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:login>
<ns1:in0>
<password>+++</password>
<user>+++</user>
</ns1:in0>
</ns1:login>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Practically is the same, but I found that there are some namespaces that my php is not applying. Why? 
I have `ns1:` where it must be `esc:` and nothing where it must be `impl:`

anyone can help me?

I'm including teh php code i'm using :

```
$login = "+++++++";
$password = "+++++++++";

$enllaç = "http://preproduccio.www14.gencat.cat/jov_titus/AppJava/services/EscolesWebService";
$impl   = 'http://impl.escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net';
$esc    = 'escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net';

$aOptions = array( "uri"=> $esc, 'location' => $enllaç,'trace'=>1 );

class loginRequest {
    private $password;
    private $user;

    public function __construct($password, $user)
    {
        $this->password     =   $password;
        $this->user         =   $user;
    }
}

$x = new loginRequest($password, $login);
$param = array('in0' => $x);


try {
    $client = new SoapClient($enllaç.'?wsdl', $aOptions);
    $clau = new SoapVar($param, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, 'http://impl.escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net'); 
    $result = $client->login($clau);
    echo "REQUEST:\n" .htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()). "<br /><br />";
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as ns1: and esc: is concerned, there is no problem.

ns1: and esc: are prefix for namespace. In the root element you specify the prefix for given namespace and later in the element refer to elements belonging to that namespace through the specified prefix.

For example in your server expected call in the root element the namespace http://escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net is given the prefix esc. so the element esc:login is resolved to be in that namespace.

In the PHP generated call the namespace http://escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net is given the prefix ns1. so the element ns1:login is resolved in the same namespace which is fine.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net">
```

if you look at the root element Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ----> this line assigns SOAP-ENV prefix to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ namespace.

so SOAP-ENV:Envelope element resolves to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ namespace

the only thing missing in your PHP call is namespace declaration of http://impl.escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net

Can you give details of your mappings - there is some mapping required to get this namespace mapped in your PHP SOAP call. Details like what PHP SOAP library are you using and what are you using for generating the SOAP Call - normally you use some serializers to convert PHP objects to SOAP elements

Comment: This is how I'm mapping the soap call : $clau = new SoapVar($param, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, 'http://impl.escoles.webservice.jovtitus.dasc.gencat.net'); 
$result = $client->login( $clau );

Comment: I've edited the question above to add more information regarding my solution. I hope it helps